Multiple Git LFS Repository in a Git Repo
Is it possible to have multiple Git LFS repo for a single Git Repo?
I have .lfsconfig file with below contents
[lfs]  

url = "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@URL"

[remote "LFSRepoB"]

lfsurl = "https://USERNAMEB:PASSWORDB@URLB"

Now, i have below folder structure in my git Repo
|-FolderA
||--FileA.cs
|-FolderB
||--NestedFolderB
|||---NestedFolder-FileB.cs
||--FileB.cs

Now i want to push files of FolderA to first URL and FolderB to LFSRepoB. Is this possible?
I have tried to add .lfsconfig with the URLB (LFSRepoB) inside FolderB, did not work.
